# Sitecore: default database upon login

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How do you change the default database used when loggin in to the backend of Sitecore?

I an solution i am currently working on, whenever a user logs in to the backend it defults to the web database and not the master as it should.
i have checked the sites definition in the web.config, but no luck - it is set to master.

Where else could i look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a number of ways this could be configured. Without actually seeing your configuration files, it is difficult to point out which.

I can tell you this however. The likely cause would either be:

1. Your site definition for the "shell" site. By default it has a content="master" attribute - by changing this, you would (likely) change the database the users work in. I say "likely", since it isn't really the recommended approach to my knowledge.
2. The same setting could also be set in a .config include file, so it may not be in the main web.config file itself.

For a reference to how these (web.config include files) work; check out http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

Comment: Thx! It was actually the content="master" attribute in the web.config that had been changed - i had been looking at the database attribute :)

Comment: It turned out this was being set in `SwitchMasterToWeb.config` for me - we will sort out which instance needs that configuration.